# Excel format rule highlight duplicates based on each date column entry

Tags: vba, excel

This excel doc is kind of like a guestbook, where there are numerous people's names and the date they visited on (written like 11/17/2014).

The doc is sorted by date, so there is like 100 or 200 names for 11/17/2014, then 200 or so for 11/18/2014...  it goes on for a bunch of consecutive dates.

I want to write a formatting rule where it highlights if there are name duplicates during the duration of each day in the date column.  This is to get rid of duplicates, and have an accurate representation of people visiting per day.

**Things I tried:**
regular dupe checker in conditional formatting - it is easy to run a dupe check all within one column.  But this is a dupe check based on two columns.  There will be many dupes for visitors returning daily.

The built-in formatting rule custom formula writer - it is easy to say "highlight all occurrences where column A cell and column B cell are equal" but not if the two cell patterns occurred more than once.

The Macro writer - I'm pretty rusty on visualbasic so I might be faster at generic dupe checking 100k or so entries by manually highlighting each day range.

**TL;DR - Highlight all where 'name' and 'date' pattern occur more than once.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

conditional formatting formula would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)>1, TRUE,FALSE)
```

dates in column "A", names in column "B", no difference if they are other way around, add conditional formatting whilst having all range selected and active in cell "A1". it WILL be slow though....

Comment: You weren't kidding!  Excel hangs like crazy.  It doesn't seem to be picking up a few duplicates I found, but I could be doing it wrong since I'm not too familiar.  The lag makes me consider checking for it another way

Comment: you can try another, quicker way, as a get around - paste the formula extract, `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)` into a column next to the original dataset, at least this way it will calculate it only once, after that paste special values on top of it and it won't be clogging up all the CPU...

Comment: Should the resulting value always be 0 or 1?  And what do you mean by paste special values on top of it?

Comment: well, if you paste the formula in previous comment in a column next to the data set, it will return the actual count of entries where data and name are the same, so anything over 1 has a duplicate.  Paste special values means, once it finishes calculating whole range, select all those cells with formulas, copy them, right click on the selection, go to paste special, select values on next menu.

Comment: This worked, but my file was just too large for excel to make this an easy task.  So future viewers of this topic should note Excel's (and their computer's) limitations.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try the alternative as per my earlier comment? it would have only pushed the calculation once, then you can work with it without having excel to recalculate it every time you kick the calculations in again. There is one more way, which would require more fiddling but would work even faster: create a pivot table from the dataset, put names down, dates across and count of any column as values, then you would need to `GETPIVOTDATA` off it for each row, then do the formatting from that cell, if the value is more than 1 then it is a duplicate